# Ubuntu 14.04 browsers extremely slow intermittent disconnection

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I am not very familiar with Ubuntu other than performing a few installations. I have been having a very odd issue with this most recent install of version 14.04. Anytime I try to use any internet browser it will work for a few seconds to a minute then it will just stop working (like the connection drops) I cant even download Chrome to see if that browser works but the browser that came preinstalled (not firefox) does not seem to be working either making me think this is more of an OS related issue. The browsers work perfectly on the windows 7 partition.

At first I tried to install 16.04 and was having the same issues, then i tried to downgrade to 14.04 thinking it was more stable and would solve my problems. I am running Windows 7 with a 4th generation i5 and 8GB of ram.

Anyone have any ideas on troubleshooting tips or what i can do to resolve this networking issue? It seems to be happening both with a wired connection and wireless.

Any help is much appreciated.